# geom_split_violin ——the same direction

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make the 'violin' direction to present in one left and one right, just like this picture:

[image]

I have tried to add `position = position_dodge(width = -0.475)` in the geom_split_violin(), but it didnt work right, it resulted in a wrong change.

```
p4 <- ggplot(mm, aes(x = material_type, y = correct, fill = feedback_type, color = test_day)) +
  introdataviz::geom_split_violin(alpha = .4, trim = F) +
  geom_boxplot(width = .2, alpha = .6, fatten = NULL, show.legend = FALSE) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_se", geom = "pointrange", show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "信息类型", labels = c("情绪性", "知识性")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "正确率", breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.2)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2", name = "社会压力形式", labels = c("具体社会压力", "平均社会压力")) +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line()) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        text = element_text(size = 16),  # 设置字体大小
        plot.title = element_text(size = 16),  # 设置标题字体大小
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16),  # 设置轴标签字体大小
        legend.title = element_text(size = 16),  # 设置图例标题字体大小
        legend.text = element_text(size = 16)) +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(test_day), scales = "free_y")
```

[image]